# check single request data into more then one column in a single table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name as directory , i am sending a three parameter 
state, city and occupation.

my table structure is as follows:

```
id, name, occupation, pro_cat1, pro_cat2, pro_cat3, pro_cat4, pro_cat5, state , city
```

so i am sending three parameter and want to get data through `IN` method.
i am using this query

```
select *
from directory
where state = '".$_REQUEST['state']."' AND
      city = '".$_REQUEST['city']."' AND
      '".$_REQUEST['occupation']."' IN
      (occupation, pro_cat1, pro_cat2, pro_cat3, pro_cat4, pro_cat5) AND
       status=1
Order by rand()
```

this query is working fine but only detect a data from occupation and pro_cat1, if i want to search in all 6 filed which i added to `IN` method then no data found msg display. 
what is the error in the query???

Comment: `search in all 6 filed which i added to IN method then no data found` ... what do you mean by this?

Comment: when i pass the parameter it only search in occupation and pro_cat1... but if the request will related to the pro_cat2 to pro_cat5 then no record found from database

Comment: Are you certain you actually have data?  Have you tried running the raw query directly from MySQL?

Comment: yes so many time, when i replace or hide the occupation and pro_cat1 then i will find the data

Comment: if  run only this select *
from directory
where    '".$_REQUEST['occupation']."' IN
      (occupation, pro_cat1, pro_cat2, pro_cat3, pro_cat4, pro_cat5) then i found the required data